# Rotativa ViewAsPdf very slow on production on windows server 2012

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, asp.net-mvc-5, rotativa

Pdf generates with css and images using @Server.MapPath("~/Content/... Loading the view (not as pdf takes secons) but generating pdf takes ages, about 5 minutes. Downloade latest wkhtmltopdf.exe but nothing solves my problem.

Please note, the pdf generates fine after intensive research about css and images and relevant files. The issue now is speed.

Comment: If you do the conversion via command line like: `wkhtmltopdf.exe http://localhost:thePort/theController/theView` how many time it takes?

Comment: try to run your project in Release configuration and see if there is any improvement

Comment: also, is the simple page load as slow as the pdf one?

Comment: Thanks for comments above. I think I'm still new in problem solving. I read a post in SO that mentioned external script as a culprit. I stripped the view down and it's faster now.

Comment: I had a slowness issue as well and it turned out to be bootstrap in the view that was slowing it down. adding argument "--print-media-type" solved the issue. Now my view was very simple and it printed basically the same, I can see if you are trying to print rich content how that may not work.